# Parse.Collection.fetch doesn't take "parse: true" option into account

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a model where I want to add a [parse](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) method in order to do extra data work (setting up a moment.js object for date fields).

But the function is never called (both model and collection).

collection :

```
class SomethingCollection extends Parse.Collection
    model: SomethingModel

    parse: ->
        console.log('parse from collection')
```

model :

```
class SomethingModel extends Parse.Object
    className: 'Something'

    parse: ->
        console.log('parse from model')
```

from a view :

```
@collection = new SomethingCollection()
@listenTo( @collection, 'add', -> console.log('fire add event') )
@collection.fetch(parse: true, silent: false, add: true)
```

EDIT :

It seems to happen in the Parse.Query.find callback, see below code comments.
So it cannot be done in the initialize method as well, but where else ? I suspect Parse.Object to be not so similar with Bakbone.Model

```
find: function(options) {
  var self = this;
  options = options || {};

  var request = Parse._request({
    route: "classes",
    className: this.className,
    method: "GET",
    useMasterKey: options.useMasterKey,
    data: this.toJSON()
  });

  return request.then(function(response) {
    return _.map(response.results, function(json) {
      var obj;
      if (response.className) {
        obj = new Parse.Object(response.className); // <- no attributes or options used, blank object
      } else {
        obj = new self.objectClass(); // <- no attributes or options used, blank object
      }
      obj._finishFetch(json, true); // <- magically do things out of any constructor or parse function
      return obj;
    });
  })._thenRunCallbacks(options);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I found no other way than to redeclare that cursed _finishFetch method :

```
original_finishFetch = _(Parse.Object.prototype._finishFetch)
Parse.Object.prototype._finishFetch = (serverData, hasData) ->
  original_finishFetch.bind(@)(@parse(serverData), hasData)
```

That way the data is processed in the parse method, as it is expected to be with any Backbone Model, or any sdk [which implements the Backbone Model interface.](https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Object.html)